# Data retrieval error in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve data from a php file named return that contains `<?php
echo 'here is a string';
?>`. I'm doing this through an html file containing ` 


  
  div { color:blue; }
  span { color:red; }
  
  
   
  var x;
  $.get("return.php", function(data){
   x = data;
 }) 
 function showAlert() {alert(x);}

$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(x);
 });

` When the button is clicked it retrieves and displays the code fine, but on the page loading, it displays "undefined" instead of the data in return.php. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

On Page loading it says undefined coz when the page load the value of x has not yet been populated. When the page loads only after than the Ajax call goes to your php file and then populates your variable x. So if you r trying to get value of x on document.ready it wont give you.